# Is there an established conjecture for prime triplets of the form (p - 2, p, p + 2)?

Tags: solution-verification

**Conjecture**: There exists no prime number p > 5 such that both p + 2 and p - 2 are prime numbers.

**Formal Proof**:

Consider any prime number p greater than 5.

p is an odd prime number, and therefore:

p - 2 and p + 2 are both odd numbers.
Every set of three consecutive integers includes a multiple of 3.
Since p > 5, we have:

p - 2 > 3
p + 2 > 7
Now, we consider the triplet (p - 2, p, p + 2):

At least one of the numbers in this triplet will be divisible by 3, due to the nature of consecutive integers.
A prime number greater than 3 cannot be divisible by 3.
Therefore, at least one of the numbers in the triplet (p - 2, p, p + 2) is not prime.

Hence, for any prime number p > 5, it is impossible for both p + 2 and p - 2 to be prime numbers.

Further, there 109,699 prime triplets of the form (p − n, p, p + n) up to 10,000 which cannot be a simple coincidence. The data speaks for itself.[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I see no reason your statement about (p-n,p,p+n) cannot be coincidence. Please offer some justification for that.

Comment: There are a lot of small primes,  hence a lot of apparent patterns amongst them.  Some are real,  others not so clear

Comment: The proposition about the triples $(p - 2, p, p + 2)$ is not a conjecture, it is a theorem (or, more accurately, a common exercise in elementary number theory). It is well known that $(3, 5, 7)$ is the largest such triple, for the reasons you gave. If you're interested in $(p - n, p, p + n)$, you might enjoy reading about [Primes in arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression).

Comment: Yes. I apologize for being ill-informed. I will enjoy reading that information. Thank you all for the kind gesture.

Comment: This information is enjoyable for me to read, as expected.